# Google Maps Api Cluster really bad performance vs super cluster

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I have to display around 15.000 markers on a Google Map.

To avoid performance issues I implemented a clustered solution.

The framework that I'm using is angular12 with @angular/google-maps.

The cose is preatty simple:

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
  <google-map
    #googleMap="googleMap"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    [center]="mapCenter"
    [zoom]="mapZoom"
    [options]="mapOptions"
    (boundsChanged)="onZoomChange()"
  >
    <map-marker-clusterer 
      *ngIf="!loading"
      (clusterClick)="onTransformersClusterMapClick($event)"
      [options]="markerClustererOptions"
      [imagePath]="transformersMarkerClustererImagePath">
      <map-marker
        #marker="mapMarker"
        *ngFor="let marker of markerList; let i = index"
        [title]="marker.title"
        [position]="{lat: +marker.lat, lng: +marker.lng}"
        (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(marker, i)"
        [options]="markerOptions"
      ></map-marker>
    </map-marker-clusterer>
  </google-map>
</div>
```

However even on the first load with a big zoom out it takes minutes to show a single cluster of 15.000 markers.
Can't tell you if I try to zoom as it almost freezes.

Trying instead a React App with google maps and supercluster package (didn't find a way to implement supercluster on angular) it takes less than a second to render a single cluster of 15.000 markers.

Is there something wrong with my angular google maps implementation, or is it just google maps api wrong?

Can I use supercluster on angular google maps?

Comment: Did you ever find the reason for this? I am currently in a similar situation.

Comment: Nope, I went with react